# Inherit css attribute value for usage on different element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a custom CSS file for a plugin I am developing and I want to use the color attribute value of certain elements from the bootstrap.css file, for instance the value of the `background-color` attribute of the `btn-primary` in twitter bootstraps css file.

I want to use that value for a different html element, let's say a `div`.

How can I achieve this is CSS?

I use Twitter Bootstrap 3, if that might help.

Comment: `<div class="btn-primary your_class"></div>`?

Comment: yeah I thought about that, but that would also inherit all the other properties and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Well, that is how it works. If used like suggested you then need to do a reset of the other properties, preferably in your `your_class`.